# pandas groupby id and month

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
data=pd.read_csv(path,sep='\t',names=['logtime','dt','uid'])
df=DataFrame(data)
uid=df['uid']
dt=sorted(df['dt'])
df1=pd.Series(uid,name='uid')
df2=pd.Series(dt,name='dt')
df=pd.concat([df1,df2],axis=1)
df= df.groupby('uid',as_index=False).agg(lambda x:x.tolist())
```

ths is my code now
this is the demo example of my dataframe before make a group by id

```
id   dt        
a   2012-01-01
a   2012-01-01
a   2012-01-02
b   2012-01-01
b   2012-02-01
c   2012-02-02 
...
ds  2013-03-01
zbd 2013-03-28
```

I want to group by month and id like and make new col times and count

```
 dt     id   times                             count         
2012-01  a  2012-01-01,2012-01-01,2012-01-02   3
         b  2012-01-01                         1
2012-02  b  2012-02-01                         1 
         c  2012-02-02                         1
       ...
2013-03  ds 2013-03-01                         1
         zbd 2013-03-28                        1
```

Comment: This is very straightforward, it's a one-liner, the only slight complication is string-appending multiple `dt` datestrings into a single `times`. Show us what you've tried, or this will likely be downvoted, closed and deleted for lack of effort.

Comment: This **should** be down voted since it has been answered countless times on SO. Here's a hint from the pandas docs: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html

Comment: Also, post a reproducible example, that means code we can execute to get your data.

Comment: ok i wil post the code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#First group by on month and id, then apply 2 functions to generate concatenated time and count in one go.

df.groupby(by=[df.dt.str[:7], 'id']).dt.agg({'Time': lambda x: ','.join(x),'Count': 
                                                     lambda y: len(y)}).reset_index()
Out[766]: 
        dt   id  Count                              Time
0  2012-01    a      3  2012-01-01,2012-01-01,2012-01-02
1  2012-01    b      1                        2012-01-01
2  2012-02    b      1                        2012-02-01
3  2012-02    c      1                        2012-02-02
4  2013-03   ds      1                        2013-03-01
5  2013-03  zbd      1                        2013-03-28
```

Answer (score 2):

```
In [84]: (df.groupby([df['dt'].dt.strftime('%Y-%m'), 'id'])['dt']
    ...:    .agg([lambda x: ','.join(x.astype(str)), 'size'])
    ...:    .rename(columns={'<lambda>':'times', 'size':'count'})
    ...:    .reset_index()
    ...: )
    ...:
Out[84]:
        dt   id                             times  count
0  2012-01    a  2012-01-01,2012-01-01,2012-01-02      3
1  2012-01    b                        2012-01-01      1
2  2012-02    b                        2012-02-01      1
3  2012-02    c                        2012-02-02      1
4  2013-03   ds                        2013-03-01      1
5  2013-03  zbd                        2013-03-28      1
```